# Only writing the relative filename from the full file name c#

Tags: c#, filepath

So I do not know if this is possible, but below I have a file path in a variable path:

```
string path = @"c:\users\povermyer\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\DanProject\PNRS
\PNRS.log";
```

What I want to do is I want to have the console window write just the last part in the path. For example, I would like the output of the console window to be:

```
The name of this file is PNRS.log
```

Is there a way to do that simply, or am I going to have to do it a long way by using a directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Path.GetFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
string path = 
    @"c:\users\povermyer\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\DanProject\PNRS\PNRS.log";
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
```

Comment: That's the same thing as  the above. I'm gonna assume @Habib beat you to the punch

Answer (score 0):

or:

```
string path = 
    @"c:\users\povermyer\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\DanProject\PNRS\PNRS.log";

string fileName = path.Split('\\').Last();
```

Comment: You *probably* need `Split('\\')` with a single quote, otherwise the above will not compile

Comment: Yes you might be right, and i did think about that, but i am only writing from the top of my head here

Comment: I have edited it out. Feel free to revert or add new :)

Comment: @Andrew http://dotnetfiddle.net/ is great for trying out simple code like this to confirm it works before posting :)